# How to get the firebase firestore document id

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am working on an application where i have list of items in recyclerview now on the recyclerview i have a heart icon when someone click on that icon that particular data added to the firebase and when again clikc on that data delete from the firebase now data is adding successully but i dont know why the data is not deleting from the firebase. please guide me

code is

```
  holder.wishlist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

            int id = holder.getBindingAdapterPosition();


            //CODE TO ADD THE ITEM TO THE WISHLIST
            if(compoundButton.isChecked())
            {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("wishlistDetails").document(uid).set(wishMap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void unused) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, "added to firestire", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {


                    }
                });


                Toast.makeText(context, "item added to wishlist" + id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else {


                //CODE TO REMOVE THE WISHLIST FROM FIREBASE
                firebaseFirestore.collection("wishlistDetails").document(datalist.get(position).getID())
                        .delete()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                Toast.makeText(context, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Because every time your are clicking onCheckedChanged is being called and it generated a new uid that does not exists in your collection.

Comment: Did UzzamAltaf's comment help?

Comment: @AlexMamo no sir i did not get it

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

1. In your wishlistmap add one more key id -- pass value uid for that key. Modify your wishlist model and add the id key.
2. Modify function for remove wishlist like below -

//CODE TO REMOVE THE WISHLIST FROM FIREBASE

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("wishlistDetails").document(list.get(position).getId())
                    .delete()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "removed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Comment: brother it is throwing     java.lang.NullPointerException: Provided document path must not be null.
 exception

Comment: please use your list name is place of list.get(position).getId()

Comment: YES bROTHER i AM USING my lists name i have updated the code also please check